# android studio cannot resolve anything? what should ı do?

Tags: android, android-studio

ı searched and ı tried all kind of things in the stackoverflow however ı could not solve it. what should ı do? even ı deleted all things and downloaded again. please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lyDE.png)

Comment: ım trying however ı have not solved it yet.

Comment: can you share your gradle

Comment: Sorry I found a solution i downloaded the sdk again :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

And this happening to only this project or for all the projects you have?

Comment: i did try. and it happens for all project.